# Multiple ruby installations, unholy mess

Tags: ruby

I've previously installed ruby 1.8.7 on my system. Some time late I installed rvm. Since then there's a giant mess. For example trying to bring up a Sinatra server results in:

```
/home/yoni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rack (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.1.3, faraday-0.8.4, koala-1.5.0, multi_json-1.3.6, multipart-post-1.1.5, rake-0.9.2.2, rubygems-bundler-0.9.0, rvm-1.11.3.3] (Gem::LoadError)
```

I know this is the result of having two ruby installations and therefore two location for gem files but I'm not sure how to fix this. I don't mind removing ruby 1.8.7 entirely, but I'd like to do it without breaking anything.

Any ideas?

**Update**: result of `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby` is:

```
libdataobjects-mysql-ruby1.8            install
libdataobjects-postgres-ruby1.8         install
libdataobjects-ruby1.8              install
libdataobjects-sqlite3-ruby1.8          install
libdbd-mysql-ruby               install
libdbd-mysql-ruby1.8                install
libdbd-sqlite3-ruby1.8              install
libdbi-ruby1.8                  install
libdeprecated-ruby1.8               install
libmysql-ruby                   install
libmysql-ruby1.8                install
libopenssl-ruby                 install
libopenssl-ruby1.8              install
libruby1.8                  install
libruby1.9.1                    deinstall
libsqlite3-ruby                 install
libsqlite3-ruby1.8              install
ruby-dev                    install
ruby1.8-dev                 install
```

Comment: How did you install ruby 1.8.7? Build from source? apt-get? What's your OS?

Comment: Sorry, should have included this in my post: Ubuntu 10.04. I installed ruby a long time ago so I can't remember if it came with the system or I had to install it. If it's any help I have a `usr/lib/ruby/1.8` directory which I didn't create myself.

Comment: Can you try dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby and see if it appears?

Comment: Result is in the update to my post.

Comment: Me too, same case, unholy mess, on Debian. Have removed rvm, kicked out 1.8.7 package, and installed 1.9 package, works since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apt-get --purge remove packagename
```

from all of the things that show up from `dkpg --list | grep ruby` that are not on the list below:

From `rvm requirements`

```
Additional Dependencies:
# For Ruby / Ruby HEAD (MRI, Rubinius, & REE), install the following:
  ruby: /usr/bin/apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
```

If it isn't possible from CLI, use synaptic package manager:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Comment: I get `Package ruby1.8 is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: Can you try sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby?

Comment: I get `Package ruby is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby-dev` and then `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby` gives the same result as before. Weird. The only output from the command is `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  firefox: Breaks: adobe-flashplugin (<= 11.1.102.63-0lucid1) but 10.0.15.3-1hardy1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`, which I'm guessing is irrelevant.

Comment: use synaptic to manually remove the packages for deletion: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto