# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 from source on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu

I just went through what looked like a pretty successful install of Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu, but when I i do ruby -v, I still get the old Ruby. My install:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Everything looks like it went off without a hitch, but still no Ruby 1.9.3. Do I need to do something extra. I couldn't find any Ruby configuration files in /etc to configure and could only find an old Ruby 1.9.1 in /usr/bin. I did the installation in my home directory.

Comment: Try ruby193 . Usually if theres name conflict, a postfix will be appended

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to mangage your Ruby installs, rather than installing from source.

Comment: Or rbenv, or rbfu. My favorite is rbfu with ruby-build.

Comment: trying to get metasploit running. it doesn't see those

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't see those?

Comment: @SunnyJuneja it doesn't see the Ruby 1.9.3 I'm running under rvm. Just the old stock Ruby 1.9.1 that wasinitially installed on the computer.

Comment: See if my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712921/multiple-ruby-installations-unholy-mess/12713246#12713246 is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter your PATH environment variable—an ordered list of paths to look in for executables—to ensure that the Ruby executable you installed is found before the standard system one. For example,

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to prepend `/usr/local/bin` before all other locations. For more on how to make this environment variable always be modified, [read this](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm).

If you want to see where various files named `ruby` may be on your system, you can use:

```
locate -b ruby      # Files with "ruby" anywhere in the name
locate -b -r ^ruby  # Files that start with "ruby"
locate -b -r ^ruby$ # Files named exactly "ruby"
```

Comment: I can't seem to find it. The only one's I see are in rvm, and I know I didn't install them there

Comment: @JohnBowlinger Install it again and look at the output to see where it was installed. The information is there, on-screen, and can be set in the configuration as well.